# SPARQL Finding the average?

Tags: sparql

I'm using a SPARQL query tool called Twinkle that doesn't seem to support functions like AVG() and SUM(). So far, only the COUNT() ARQ function works. Is there an alternative way to sum numbers so that I can at least divide using COUNT()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so. Switch tools and use something that supports SPARQL 1.1.

Comment: +1 As Richard says Twinkle is an old tool that hasn't been updated in several years, find and use a newer tool